# Find second to last word in a string C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-c++

Hi I need to find **second to last word** in a `string`. Right now below program is printing the last one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text{"some line with text"};
    // find last space, counting from backwards
    int i = text.length() - 2; // last character
    while (i != 0 && !isspace(text[i]))
    {
      --i;
    }
    string lastword = text.substr(i+1); // +1 to skip leading space
    cout << lastword << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: (Printing last word)

```
text
```

Comment: Just take the code that you already have and continue iterating until you find the next space.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into words and hold the previous word before saving the current word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string text{"some line with text"};
    std::stringstream ss(text);
    std::string previousword, lastword, newword;
    while (ss >> newword) {
        previousword = lastword;
        lastword = newword;
    }
    std::cout << previousword << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that using `using namespace std;` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Beware that this will iterate over the entire text to find the last word.

Comment: This would make it faster: `std::stringstream ss ({text.rbegin(), text.rend()});`, then just take the second word.

Comment: Keep in mind that in this case, the word will be reversed.

Comment: Then reverse the reversed word: `std::string(secondword.rbegin(), secondword.rend())`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any loops. Just add error checking:

```
int main() {
  std::string text{ "some line with text" };
  std::size_t pos2 = text.rfind(' ');
  std::size_t pos1 = text.rfind(' ', pos2-1);

  std::cout << text.substr(pos1+1, pos2-pos1-1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep counting spaces until you arrive to the word you want or use a stringstream as MikeCAT proposed.

Here there is a function that finds any last word number without having to copy the entire string in a stringstream:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

string getNLastWord(string text, int n)
{
    bool insideAWord = false;
    int wordNum = 0;
    int wordEnd = -1;
    for(int i = text.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(text[i] != ' ' && !insideAWord)
        {
            wordNum++;
            insideAWord = true;
        }
        else if(text[i] == ' ')
        {
            insideAWord = false;
        }
        if(wordNum == n)
        {
            wordEnd = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(wordEnd == -1)
    {
        cout << "There are no " << n << " words from right." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int wordStart;
        for(wordStart = wordEnd; wordStart > 0; wordStart--)
        {
            if(text[wordStart] == ' ')
            {
                wordStart++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return text.substr(wordStart,wordEnd+1-wordStart);
    }
    return "";
}

int main() {
    string text = "some text";
    cout << getNLastWord(text,2);
    return 0;
}
```